# Como puedo darle formato a múltiples valores de un formulario que van a un archivo php?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Hola mi problema es que necesito que los multiples valores que mi formulario manda a otro archivo php mediante method POST, se reciban con un formato de esta manera:  "deny_countries": ["AF","AX","AL"] donde los valores que se envian son AF AX AL obtenidos de mi formulario. Necesito que cada valor esté entre comillas y se separen por comas, excepto el último valor que ya no debería tener coma.

OJO: RECIBO TODOS LOS VALORES SELECCIONADOS SIN PROBLEMA, EL PROBLEMA ES DARLES EL FORMATO QUE ME PIDE LA API

Adjunto ambos codigos:

FORMULARIO

```
 <form method="POST" action="algo.php">
<label class="form-label" for="select2-multiple">Multiple</label>
<select data-placeholder="Selecciona multiples paises" class="select2 form-select" id="select2-multiple" name="select2-multiple[]" multiple>
<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="AX">Aland Islands</option>
<option value="AL">Albania</option>
<option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
<option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
</select>
<button class="go-btn" name="submit" type="submit"> 
 Enviar
</button>
</form>
```

algo.php

```
 <?php//visualizo como llega mi info
 $values = $_POST['select2-multiple'];
 foreach ($values as $a){
 echo $a;
  }
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dealgo.com/v1/wmsauth/groups/59135ad8796db44a2b0004a3/rules/id=6164b6&api_key=f993dd');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
 $headers = array(
 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
 'Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8'
 );
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 $data = '{
"allow_countries": [""], 
"deny_countries": ["AF","AX","AL"]      //aqui necesito los values con este formato
}
';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: En mi código ya están puestos los corchetes, y se mandan correctamente todos los valores que se seleccionan, pero se mandan juntos o sea: AXAFAR cuando yo quiero recibir "AX", "AF", AR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario crear el formato manualmente, puedes armar un arreglo asociativo y generar la cadena con [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php
//visualizo como llega mi info
$values = $_POST['select2-multiple'];
// Con var_dump() puedes ver todo el contenido sin un ciclo
// var_dump($values); // Quítalo, ya no es necesario

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.dealgo.com/v1/wmsauth/groups/59135ad8796db44a2b0004a3/rules/id=6164b6&api_key=f993dd');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Accept: application/json; charset=utf-8'
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Creas un arreglo asociativo
$data = [
    // ¿Debe ser arreglo vacío o con una cadena vacía?
    'allow_countries' => [],
    // Agregas lo que obtuviste de $_POST
    'deny_countries' => $values
];
// Verificar lo que se va a enviar
var_dump(json_encode($data));

// Envias el arreglo codificado en JSON
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
// Ver respuesta del servidor
var_dump($result);
```

Solo queda que verifiques si el arreglo para `allow_countries` debe estar vacío `[]` o incluir una cadena vacía `['']`.

Con las modificaciones realizadas, deberías ver primero la estructura de datos que se va a enviar, algo como:

```
string(x) { "allow_countries": [], "deny_countries": ["AF", "AX"] }
```

Donde `x` es la longitud de la cadena generada.

Al final, deberías ver el mensaje que devuelve el servidor.

Comment: Hola Triby, primero que nada, quiero agradecerte por la ayuda que me estas brindando.
El codigo que me brindaste no funcionó, me da error 500, pero aun asi , si hubiera funcionado, tengo un problema mayor que el solo recibir la variable $values en 'deny_countries'  si yo solo lo recibo desde post, los valores del formulario vienen en este formato AXARAZ (por poner un ejemplo de 3 paises), y no los puedo pasar asi a 'deny_countries', tienen que estar asi: ["AX","AR","AZ"] cada uno esta entrecomillado, y separados por coma, excepto el ultimo. Ese es mi verdadero problema, me puedes ayudar?

Comment: Esto es lo que me da var dump: 
array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "AF" [1]=> string(2) "AX" [2]=> string(2) "AL" }

no me sale absolutamente ningun error en los logs

Comment: Hola Triby, ya pude corregir el codigo y ya no me da error 500, ya solo me sale el arreglo, pero al ejecutar el php no se ve traducido el cambio en la api, es decir, los paises seleccionados en el arreglo, no se envian bien, no se si sea cuestion de falta de coma, o incluso algunas comillas mal puestas. esta es la url del form.
https://panelcws.com/axel/stack.php

Comment: Triby nuevamente muchas gracias, se que estamos cerca, ya puse la linea que me pediste y veo los datos que esta enviando,te envio 2 urls, 
Esta funciona bien, manda los datos a la api y esta la registra, solo que tengo que poner los datos manualmente: 
https://panelcws.com/axel/stack2.php
$data = '{
  "deny_countries": ["AR","FR","MX"]
 }';
y esta 
https://panelcws.com/axel/stack.php es la que tu me enviaste.
$data = [
     'deny_countries' => $values
 ];
Esta segunda, cambia en como envia, y la api no la registra. cuando envío stack2 se que funciona porque se refleja en una url

Comment: @AxelGomez, actualicé la respuesta con las sugerencias que te había comentado para ver cómo se envían los datos y lo que responde el servidor.

Comment: Eres dios ya la api los recibe bien, de hecho si lo quieres probar, ya veras la respuesta que regresa el servidor de la api, ya se registran ahi los paises.
Te agradezco muchisimo!!!